# terraform google custom image from another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I know this is possible from the console but, how do you initialize a boot disk image from another project within terraform?

This is what I have so far but it states it cannot find the image:

```
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
    image = "cof-ubuntu1604-180124"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the correct address for the disk on the field "image".

First you need to be sure that you can access the image from your project, see [here for info about sharing images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/sharing-images-across-projects)

Then, the "image" variable you are using has to point to the correct URI. It will look like this:

```
"selfLink": "projects/ndjanuary-190908/global/images/ffs12354",
```

You can get that information from the Compute Engine API, using the method "compute.images.get" my request looked like this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/ndjanuary-190908/global/images/ffs12354?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Here is the link to the relevant API explorer:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/image/m/compute/v1/compute.images.get

Answer (score 1):

The image is not the image name, it is the URI of the image.

```
data "google_compute_image" "my_image" {
  name = "cof-ubuntu1604-180124"
  # could also use family = "family-name"
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "test"
  ...

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${data.google_compute_image.my_image.self_link}"
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Reference:

[google_compute_image](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/d/datasource_compute_image.html)

Answer (score 0):

The answers provided were bOth very helpful and solved my issues. THe use of the API Explorer was invaluable to fining the correct URI.